# pell js cannot remove original css style on text when pasted on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using pell5js to convert my text to HTML format.

but I encounter this problem when I paste a text from a certain webpage to my textarea with pell it looks like this.

[image]

and the HTML output for this content looks like this

[image]

the output was different when I pasted a plain text to my textarea
is there a way to remove the styles that were embedded in the text and retain the style which pell provided?

or is there other plugins that can convert its original HTML format to plain text then when submit convert it to HTML format provided by the plugin?